# Detect working CustomEvent constructor

Tags: javascript

I want to test whether the [`CustomEvent` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent) is supported.

```
var ev;

if (/* CustomEvent constructor supported? */) {
    ev = new CustomEvent('splat');
} else {
    ev = document.createEvent('Event');
    ev.initEvent('splat');
}

this.dispatchEvent(ev);
```

I don't have any machines running IE nearby to test it. Does it throw an error so I can use try/catch, or do I need to do something else? What about older non-IE browsers?

Comment: If nobody beats me to it, I'll probably drag out some old browsers and self-answer when I have more time. I'm just hoping someone already knows the answer.

Answer (score 15):

The following should work, even on IE6, i've tested it on an old XP machine with IE6.

```
if (typeof CustomEvent === 'function') {
    ev = new CustomEvent('splat');
}
```

Comment: So `window.CustomEvent` is undefined in old IE? Somehow the MDN docs gave me the impression that it still existed in older browsers, but didn't work as a constructor.

Comment: In IE11, it's type is 'object', not 'function'

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, try/catch should work, ie8 will throw:

```
TypeError: 'CustomEvent' is undefined
```

Whereas ie11 will throw:

```
Object doesn't support this action
```

Other older browsers will either have not implemented it at all, or not as a constructor, so should result in similar errors

so you could do something like:

```
var isSupported = (function() { 
  try {
    new CustomEvent('test');
    return true;
  } catch (e) {
    return false;
  }
})();
```

Comment: This does not directly answer the question, can you please clarify if the try catch will work in this case or if any additional action is needed.

Comment: Thank you mate! That's exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

The MDN docs state that it's IE9 and above.

A check like this might be good enough:

```
if (window["CustomEvent"] === undefined) {
    // Do stuff to add custom event class
}
```

Sorry jsfiddle doesn't support IE8.

Comment: In IE11, `window.CustomEvent` is present, but doesn't work as a constructor.